# How to append an array of lists to data grid view using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to append data in array of lists to datagrid view, lets say my array of lists is:

```
         public List<match> [] m = new List<match>[100];
```

and the lists are already filled, then how can i append them all to datagrid view

Comment: When you use a `List<T>` as a `DataSource` to the `DataGridView`… any “collection” property in `T` will not display as a “Collection.” The grid is not going to know what to do with a cell that has “multiple” values. That is why you are getting the count and capacity. If you want multiple values in the cell… like a combo box… you will need to add them manually. In addition, it looks odd that you have an array of 100 `List<match>[100]`??? this structure alone is not going to display in the grid because each item in the array is a `List` and it is unknown what `match` contains.

Comment: You may want to clarify what is not working as expected. Currently this question is too broad and needs further clarification. At the least you should supply/post what `match` is.